# Printing babel date.gregorian strings

Tags: babel

I am creating a `babel` `.ini` file for my language, and I want to create an accompanying document that lists all strings defined in the said file. For `captions`, I can do this by calling `\[key]name` (e.g., `\prefacename`).

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\keyitem}{m}{%
    \item[#1] \expandafter\csname#1name\endcsname\relax%
}

\begin{description}
    \keyitem{preface}
    % More strings
\end{description}
```

Is there a way I can do this for `date.gregorian`? I would like to be able to print the `wide`, `abbreviated`, and `narrow` strings. I have tried `\monthiname`, etc. but I get an "Undefined control sequence" error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve them with `\getlocaleproperty`. For example and with an existing locale:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[spanish, provide=*]{babel}

\begin{document}

\getlocaleproperty{\result}{spanish}{date.gregorian/days.abbreviated.mon}
\result

\getlocaleproperty{\result}{spanish}{date.gregorian/days.abbreviated.tue}
\result

\end{document}
```

will print:

> lun
> mar

The first argument is set to the value of the key in the last argument (the section and the key are separated with `/`).

Comment: Thank you for this! I'd like to add that the captions must be loaded via `provide=*` package option or `\babelprovide`.